# KivyMD while loop in background

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

```
import threading
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRectangleFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField



class DemoApp(MDApp,threading.Thread):
   
    def build(self):
        screen = Screen()

        self.data_table = MDDataTable(pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.4}, size_hint=(0.7, 0.7), check=True,
                                      rows_num=20,
                                      column_data=[
                                          ("FullName", dp(60)),
                                          ("EntryDate", dp(35)),
                                          ("EntryTime", dp(35)),
                                          ("Punch", dp(35))],
                                      row_data=[ ])
    
        count=0
        while count < 100 : 
            self.newrow()
            count+=1
        screen.add_widget(self.data_table)
        self.newrow()
        return screen
  
    def newrow(self):
        no = 0
        no = len(self.data_table.row_data)+1
        self.data_table.row_data.insert(len(self.data_table.row_data),(no,'jacob','lino','eeedebus'))
        # print(self.icode.text, self.iname.text, self.iprice.text)
        print(self.data_table.row_data)
        return self.data_table.row_data  

DemoApp().run()
```

Above is the code and when  i try to run the program it will wait for the while loop to finish before loading the app. How can i run the while loop in backgroun? and so that the program will be usable while the loop is running on background

by the way i am a beginner in kivy thank you for your help

Comment: I've already fixed this issue, by creating a function and call it using a threading, I'll update my code above

Comment: You could've used `Clock` to update data in this case as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated code that fixed my issue thank you.
I used threading to run it in background while the app is running

```
import threading
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRectangleFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
import time
class DemoApp(MDApp,threading.Thread):
    def build(self):
      
        a=self.test()
       
        return a
    def test(self):
        screen = Screen()
        self.data_table = MDDataTable(pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.4}, size_hint=(0.7, 0.7), check=True,
                                    rows_num=20,
                                    column_data=[
                                        ("FullName", dp(60)),
                                        ("EntryDate", dp(35)),
                                        ("EntryTime", dp(35)),
                                        ("Punch", dp(35))],
                                    row_data=[ ])
        count=0
        threading.Thread(target=self.bgprocess).start()
        screen.add_widget(self.data_table)
        return screen
    def bgprocess(self): 
        count =0
        while count < 100 :
            print("Jacob") 
DemoApp().run()
```